# How to get Activity containerViewId from click event on item in ViewPager fragment nested in NavigationView Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I have an Activity with a NavigationView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.app.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/containerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" ></RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

On starting the app, or on clicking a NavigationView item, the following is called:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.containerView, new NavFragment()).commit();
```

where:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

`NavFragment` has the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/tabContainer">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and contains a tabbed ViewPager:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_frag, container, false);
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        return rootView;
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        String tab1 = getResources().getString(R.string.tab_1);
        String tab2= getResources().getString(R.string.tab_2);
        String tab3 = getResources().getString(R.string.tab_3);

        adapter.addFragment(new Frag1(), tab1);
        adapter.addFragment(new Frag2(), tab2);
        adapter.addFragment(new Frag3(), tab3);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Then each `ViewPager` fragment contains its own `RecyclerView` with items.

Now my question is what do I put in the `onClick` for the `RecyclerView` items in the nested `ViewPager` tabs, calls the same main container, `containView` that is in the `MainActivity` layout?
That is, how do I reference that container? Basically, I need the new fragment to replace the `tablayout` and `ViewPager`. Then on clicking the back button, for it to return to the `ViewPager` location where the item was clicked, the way it would happen when calling new activity.
Think along the lines of:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.containerView, new ClickedItemFrag()).commit();
```

The point of calling a fragment instead of a new activity is to maintain everything inside the `NavigationView`. I've looked and looked, but I can't find a working solution to my dilemma of trying to reference the `containerView`.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I tried to use:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(((ViewGroup)getView().getParent()).getId(), ClickedItemFrag()).commit();
```

gives:

```
09-27 12:48:16.720 17000-17000/com.example.app E/FragmentManager: No view found for id 0x7f0d0138 (com.example.app:id/viewpager) for fragment ClickedItemFrag{b189f1c #0 id=0x7f0d0138}
```

Then:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(((ViewGroup)getView().getParent().getParent()).getId(), ClickedItemFrag()).commit();
```

gives:

```
09-27 12:43:12.999 13621-13621/com.example.app E/FragmentManager: No view found for id 0x7f0d0135 (com.example.app:id/tabContainer) for fragment ClickedItemFrag{68c33f0 #0 id=0x7f0d0135}
```

Then:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(((ViewGroup)getView().getParent().getParent().getParent()).getId(), ClickedItemFrag()).commit();
```

gives:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d0075 (com.example.app:id/containerView) for fragment ClickedItemFrag{4f136ab #0 id=0x7f0d0075}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your Activity which contains all your Layout add the method `navigateToFragment()`:

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // ..Your code here

    public void navigateToFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.containerView, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Then when an item inside your RecyclerView is clicked you call `navigateToFragment()` from your Frag1, Frag2, Frag3 fragments:

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).navigateToFragment(new ClickedItemFrag());
```

Comment: You can ask If you don't understand something.

Comment: You, are quite simply an incredible human being! Thank you so much for being alive and even more for being you! Your solution is brilliant and makes perfect sense, after I've been racking my brain to figure it out. You've made my day, thank you sooo much!